# same models for multiple subdomains and sites

Tags: codeigniter

I have multiple sites (some are subdomains, some are other sites) that run off of the same database && caching.  Currently, each of these projects has a unique controller / view setup but the same models.  I'm running into the problem where I want the same models for each of the sites as keeping them all up to date is a pain.

Question: how would I keep the same models over multiple sites / subdomains when each have their own views / controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this thread](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/136321/) for inspiration. If you're on a *NIX box the accepted convention is to use [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to a share a `models` folder outside your application directory. If you inspect `sys/core/Loader.php` you'll find that's where the path construction resides and so some of the folks in the thread discuss a `MY_Loader.php` alternative. Unfortunately the `sys/core/Loader.php` code is complicated by the "Packages" that CodeIgniter supports, so it's not a easy string change.

Comment: I know that this was many months ago, but I thought I'd give you an update.  I actually made one of the sites an API and the lower-traffic sites simply call on the given API to get their information from the model.  Not a perfect solution, but it works decently well.